# Where can I ask for a web site that I'm looking for?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a web site where I can create questions about programming, HTML and CSS and my students can answer it with actual code.

I know Stack Exchange has many sites for asking different types of questions ordered by theme; what site should I use for a question of that type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think such a website would qualify as a web *application*, and your question would therefore be on-topic for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Their scope is not limited to installable software; [web application requests](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps) work as well, provided they meet the [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Here is some more discussion on their own Meta about the difference between web*sites* and web *applications*, and why website requests are off-topic: [Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/191/23377)